# Get and be - when should each of them be used?

Tags: sentence-construction

here is a motivational sentence about exercising and I'm not sure if it is correct.

> Challenge yourself, push yourself and every day you will **get** better and stronger and every day you will **be** one step closer to your goal.

I'm not sure about using **be** and **get**. I prefer **be** (...will be one step...) but I think it's more passive. Should I use **get** instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern English has an alternative passive with "get" instead of "be" (eg "get eaten") but that's not what is in view here.

With an adjective implying change, "be" is used for the state, "get" for the process of reaching that state - it is really a synonym of "become", perhaps with a connotation of actively making the change happen.

So "get better" means something like "work to become better".

You can see the same difference with "one step closer": "you will be one step closer" means "(by/after doing all this) you will be positioned one step closer". "You will get one step closer" would mean "You will move yourself one step closer", and seems to me to repeat what comes before.

Comment: I don't *really* understand exactly what you're saying here, so this isn't to imply that I disagree in any way. But to my mind, *in principle* OP's two highlighted verbs could be ***get+be, be+get, get+get,*** or ***be+be***, with no significant effect on the meaning (or "idiomacy", come to that). But I do think there's a potentially significant difference between *I will **get** better tomorrow* and *I will **be** better tomorrow*. The former implies the improvement won't *start* until tomorrow, where the latter simply means it won't be *manifest* until then, even if it's already underway.